# How do I display Django ManyToMany on a template? Simple code needed

Tags: django

I am trying to display ManyToMany field on the template in reversed order.

Here is what I mean:

I managed to display ManyToMany field on template when ManyToMany field was a field in model used so for example:

```
<br/>{% for tag in post.tag.all %}{{ tag }}<br/>{% endfor %}
```

will display all of the tags(meaning categories) that the post belongs to based on this model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True,null=True,related_name='tag')
```

Now I want something opposite - display authors of the post when ManyToMany field is in the Author model (Post model above stays the same):

```
class Person(models.Model):
post=models.ManyToManyField(Post,blank=True,null=True,related_name='post')
```

I am quite sure it has something to do with Related Object Reference ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/)

Just can not make it work.

I have tried the following on the template.

```
{% for post in posts %}
{% for author in post.person_set.all %}{{author}}<br/>{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, shall I do this kind of searches on the template like above or is it a better practice put this kind of searches in views...resourcewise.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Since you have set `related_name` to `'post'` (which is *not* a good idea), you should write `{% for author in post.post.all %}`, bu tthe real error is that you did a poor job with the `related_name`s.

Comment: You don't need to define the ManyToManyField on both sides of the relation. Pick one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I'm not convinced he does, the m2m in `Post` refers to `Tag`, not to `Person`.

Comment: There was no double referencing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding on what the [**`related_name=`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) does. Like the documentation says:

> The name to use for the relation **from the related object back to this one**. (...)

So it is the name of the relation in *reverse*. In order to make your models "sound", you thus should name it like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, blank=True, null=True, related_name='authors')
```

It also makes sense here to use the *plural*, so `posts` instead of `post`.

In that case, you thus can render this with:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for author in post.authors.all %}{{author}}<br/>{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that if you want to render all the values for `ManyToManyField`s, you better use [**`.prefetch_related(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in the queryset to prefetch the `Person`,s otherwise rendering the template will result in a lot of extra queries.